# gofpdfでPDF中に日本語を表示させる方法

Tags: go, pdf, gofpdf

gofpdfを用いてドキュメント中に日本語を含むPDFを出力しようとしましたが、日本語部分だけ文字化けします。

試しに次のコードを実行してPDFを出力してみました。元ネタはhttps://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gofpdf のコードです。

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/gofpdf"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "../font")
    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetFont("Arial", "B", 16)
    pdf.Cell(40, 10, "GoでPDF!")
    pdf.Output(os.Stdout)
}
```

生成したPDFをAdobe Readerで表示させたものが次の画像です。

[image: 生成されたpdf]

環境は次の通りです。

- Mac OS X 10.9.5
- Go 1.3

Comment: ドキュメントに`this package does not yet support UTF-8 fonts`と記述があります

Comment: 試してみましたが、日本語は、タイトル等のメタ情報のみにしか設定できませんでした。これ残念ですね、開発者は中国の方の様なのに…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h2so5 さんのおっしゃる通り、gofpdf はまだ UTF-8 文字列に対応していません。

ご質問の主旨からは外れますが、以下は新規のフォントを登録する手順です。

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/gofpdf/makefont
$ go build makefont.go
$ ./makefont --dst=../font --embed --enc=../font/[encoding map file] [ttf font file path]
```

※ `--enc` オプションに指定する encoding map に、UTF-8 用のものがまだ用意されていません

上記を実行すると、デフォルトのフォントパスである `gofpdf/font` ディレクトリにフォント情報(*.json, *.ttf など)が置かれます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。makefont.goの中を読み進めてみたところ、そもそもマルチバイトのコードポイントを現時点ではサポートしてない感じですね。。。(´･_･`)

Answer (score 1):

すぐに試せる環境が手元にないため、確証がない回答となります。申し訳ありません。

`Arial` は英文フォントのため、日本語が出力できていないのではないかと考えられます。
和文フォントを指定してみてください。